# how to configure api route in spring-cloud-gateway in kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-gateway, kind

Im learning kubernetes and im trying to run my microservices on kind cluster.
I have a backend API microservice which runs on `containerPort: 8080`.
I have exposed the port `18080` and mapped it to the backend API service. Im able to access the API from my local machine i.e. my laptop.
Here is the yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bookmarker-api-svc
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: bookmarker-api-pod
  ports:
    - name: app-port-mapping
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30090
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bookmarker-api-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bookmarker-api-pod
  template:
    metadata:
  labels:
    app: bookmarker-api-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: bookmarked
          image: manjosh1990/bookmarker-api-jib
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
```

I have an spring cloud gateway microservice which runs my react code as well.
Im trying to route any request to certain path to my backend service. Here is how I have configured my routes

```
server:
  port: 10443
spring:
  application:
    name: bookmark-api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: bookmark-api
          uri: ${BOOKMARK_API_URI}
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/bookmarks/**
```

When i replace this `${BOOKMARK_API_URI}` with `http://localhost:18080` and run the api gateway on my host machine it routes the requests correctly to my backend service.

but im trying run this as a pod and access it, but it fails to route.
Here is the configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bookmarker-ui-svc
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: bookmarker-ui-pod
  ports:
    - name: app-port-mapping
      protocol: TCP
      port: 10443
      targetPort: 10443
      nodePort: 30080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bookmarker-ui-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bookmarker-ui-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bookmarker-ui-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: bookmarker-ui
          image: manjosh1990/bookmarker-gui
          ports:
            - containerPort: 10443
          env:
            - name: BOOKMARK_API_URI
              value: http://bookmarker-api-svc:8080
```

With this configuration it does not route.

i logged in to the pod and tried to run the curl on `http://bookmarker-api-svc:8080`, I'm able to successfully access the api

> root@bookmarker-ui-deployment-5bb7b65bd-q4drr:/# curl http://bookmarker-api-svc:8080/api/bookmarks/
> {"data":[{"id":551,"title":"SpringBoot Integration Testing using TestContainers Starter","url":"https://sivalabs.in/2020/02/spring-boot-integration-testing-using-testcontainers-starter","createdAt":"2023-09-18T15:00:56.857853Z"},{"id":501,"title":"Deserialize Immutable Objects with Jackson","url":"https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-immutable-objects","createdAt":"2023-09-18T15:00:56.857853Z"},{"id":451,"title":"Achieving framework-independent zen with the power of interfaces and hexagonal architecture","url":"https://rskupnik.github.io/framework-independence-with-hexagonal-architecture","createdAt":"2023-09-18T15:00:56.857853Z"},{"id":401,"title":"How to teach Git","url":"https://rachelcarmena.github.io/2018/12/12/how-to-teach-git.html","createdAt":"2023-09-18T15:00:56.857853Z"},{"id":351,"title":"Build a JavaScript Command Line Interface (CLI) with Node.js","url":"https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-command-line-interface-cli-node-js","createdAt":"2023-09-18T15:00:56.857853Z"},{"id":251,"title":"Java Microservices: A Practical Guide","url":"https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/java-microservices-a-practical-guide","createdAt":"2023-09-18T15:00:56.857853Z"},{"id":1,"title":"How To Remove Docker Containers, Images, Volumes, and Networks","url":"https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-volumes-and-networks","createdAt":"2023-09-18T15:00:56.857853Z"},{"id":151,"title":"A categorized list of all Java and JVM features since JDK 8","url":"https://advancedweb.hu/2019/02/19/post_java_8","createdAt":"2023-09-18T15:00:56.857853Z"},{"id":101,"title":"Spring Boot Security Jwt Authentication","url":"https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-jwt-auth","createdAt":"2023-09-18T15:00:56.857853Z"},{"id":301,"title":"Spring Boot integration with p6spy, datasource-proxy, flexy-pool and spring-cloud-sleuth","url":"https://github.com/gavlyukovskiy/spring-boot-data-source-decorator","createdAt":"2023-09-18T15:00:56.857853Z"}],"totalElements":12,"totalPages":2,"currentPage":1,"hasNext":true,"hasPreroot@bookmarker-ui-deployment-5bb7b65bd-q4drr:/#

Here is my kind config:

```
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
kind: Cluster
name: manjosh-k8s
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  kubeadmConfigPatches:
  - |
    kind: InitConfiguration
    nodeRegistration:
      kubeletExtraArgs:
        node-labels: "ingress-ready=true"
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 80
    hostPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 443
    hostPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 30090
    hostPort: 18080
    protocol: TCP
  - containerPort: 30080
    hostPort: 30080
    protocol: TCP
```

i found that from the client(browser) `http://localhost:10443/api/bookmarks/` . This port is actually hard-coded in my reactjs application. I changed this port to `30080` and now the browser calls `http://localhost:30080/api/bookmarks/` and it is working. But now I don't want to hardcode this port in the react application.

Please advise

Comment: do you actually see the environment variable in pod when you run `echo $BOOKMARK_API_URI`?

Comment: yes
`root@bookmarker-ui-deployment-5bb7b65bd-q4drr:/# echo $BOOKMARK_API_URI
http://bookmarker-api-svc:8080
`

Comment: i found that from the client(browser) `http://localhost:10443/api/bookmarks/` . This port is actually hard-coded in my reactjs application. I changed this port to `30080`; now the browser calls `http://localhost:30080/api/bookmarks/` and it is working. But now I don't want to hardcode this port in the react application.

Comment: Not sure how it fits in your use case but you can try exploring the type LoadBalancer instead of NodePort. And use the configured LoadBalancer URL in the React application

Comment: @VipulKumar With this approach it is still tightly coupled to the load balancer URL, what I want is somehow to make it configurable outside the react application.